# Who is “our greatest living phonetic expert” in “Ulysses”?

Tags: james-joyce, ulysses

In chapter 12 of James Joyce’s *Ulysses*, the narrator describes an “exhibition of cynanthropy” which

> comprises, among other achievements, the recitation of verse. **Our greatest living phonetic expert** (wild horses shall not drag it from us!) has left no stone unturned in his efforts to delucidate and compare the verse recited and has found it bears a *striking* resemblance (the italics are ours) to the ranns of the ancient Celtic bards.
>
> —Page 256 of the Gabler edition (12.719-20)

The parenthetical about wild horses seems like a challenge from Joyce to the reader to decipher the identity of this expert in the pronunciation of the Irish language. Is it A.E. or one of the other characters we met in the National Library?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The passage quoted in the question continues as follows:

> Our greatest living phonetic expert (wild horses shall not drag it from us!) has left no stone unturned in his efforts to delucidate and compare the verse recited and has found it bears a *striking* resemblance (the italics are ours) to the ranns† of ancient Celtic bards. We are not speaking so much of those delightful lovesongs with which the writer who conceals his identity under the graceful pseudonym of the **Little Sweet Branch** has familiarised the bookloving world but rather (as a contributor D. O. C. points out in an interesting communication published by an evening contemporary) of the harsher and more personal note which is found in the satirical effusions of the famous Raftery and of Donal MacConsidine to say nothing of a more modern lyrist at present very much in the public eye. We subjoin a specimen which has been rendered into English by an eminent scholar whose name for the moment we are not at liberty to disclose though we believe that our readers will find the topical allusion rather more than an indication. The metrical system of the canine original, which recalls the intricate alliterative and isosyllabic rules of the Welsh englyn,‡ is infinitely more complicated but we believe our readers will agree that the spirit has been well caught.
>
> <sub>James Joyce (1922). [*Ulysses*, chapter 12](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/4300/4300-h/4300-h.htm#chap12). Project Gutenberg.</sub>
>
> <sub>† “A piece of Irish verse; a stanza, a quatrain” (*OED*) ‡ “In Welsh poetry, a stanza (now always a quatrain) of a certain metrical structure” (*OED*)</sub>

The pseudonym indicates that this is [**Douglas Hyde**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Hyde), a leading figure in the Gaelic revival of the late 19th century, who published under the pen-name **An Craoibhín Aoibhinn** meaning “Little Sweet Branch”. Joyce’s description of him as the “greatest living phonetic expert” is likely sarcastic, for, as a child, Hyde had developed his own phonetic system to transcribe the Irish language:

> Irish was a language he had to learn viva voce […]. Using symbols and spellings from French, Greek, English, and (later, when he was introduced to it) German, Douglas devised for himself as a study aid a phonetic system from which he could record in writing the useful phrases, wise sayings, and snatches of poetry and song that he was then acquiring daily. “*Noreya ve dhoul rotin*,” Douglas’s phonetic rendering of *nuair bhí an diabhal ró-tinn* (when the devil was very sick), a case in point, begins one of the many Irish-language stories he transcribed in his exercise book, using the system he had developed.
>
> <sub>Janet Egleson Dunleavy & Gareth W. Dunleavy (1991). [*Douglas Hyde: A Maker of Modern Ireland*, p. 30](https://archive.org/details/douglashydemaker0000dunl/page/30/mode/2up). University of California Press.</sub>

Joyce’s emphasis on “striking” picks out a word that Hyde was over-fond of:

> Who were those Celts, of whose race the Irish are to-day perhaps the most **striking** representatives? (p. 1)
> One of the most **striking** features of their external policy (p. 6)
> The complete difference between the names of the Indian, Hellenic, Italic, Teutonic, and Celtic gods is very **striking** (p. 14)
> a land which presents so many and so **striking** analogies (p. 58)
> The classical reader need hardly be reminded of the **striking** resemblance (p. 111)
> parallels […] which seem altogether too **striking** to be fortuitous (p. 198)
> A **striking** passage in one of Renan’s books (p. 225)
> the most **striking** king that ever reigned in pagan Ireland (p. 246)
> to which he receives the following **striking** answer (p. 248)
> A **striking** instance of how the Ossianic tale continued to develop (p. 375)
> one of the most **striking** figures in both the literary and political history (pp. 419–420)
>
> <sub>Douglas Hyde (1899). [*A Literary History of Ireland from Earliest Times to the Present Day*](https://archive.org/details/cu31924016852935). London: T. F. Unwin.</sub>

In the remainder of the paragraph in *Ulysses*, Joyce continues to allude to and parody Hyde’s works:

> ‘Those delightful lovesongs’ are [*The Love Songs of Connacht*](https://archive.org/details/LoveSongsOfConnacht), a collection of Gaelic folk ballads which Hyde gathered and first published, with his own English renderings, in 1893. Anthony Raftery was an itinerant bard of the early nineteenth century whose poems, extant until then only in oral tradition, were rescued from oblivion and edited by Hyde in 1903. MacConsidine, another collector of Irish folklore, is cited a number of times in the notes to *The Love Songs of Connacht*. The talk of ‘intricate alliterative and isosyllabic rules of the Welsh englyn’ is a fair sample of the somewhat turgid style of Hyde’s [*Literary History of Ireland*](https://archive.org/details/cu31924016852935). Garryowen’s poem, which completes the interpolation, is in the form of a curse, a genre of Irish poetry familiar, of course, to Hyde, who includes some examples in another of his collections with the observation that ‘This book would not be complete without one or two of them being in it.’†
>
> <sub>Alan M. Cohn (1962). ‘[Douglas Hyde in *Ulysses*](https://doi.org/10.1080/00138386208597147)’. *English Studies* 43:1–6, p. 256.</sub>
>
> <sub>† Douglas Hyde (1906). [*The Religious Songs of Connacht*, p. 267](https://archive.org/details/religioussongsof02hydeiala/page/266/mode/2up). Dublin: M. H. Gill and Son.</sub>

There does not seem to be a consensus on whom Joyce meant by “a more modern lyrist at present very much in the public eye”.

> The anonymous “more modern lyrist” could potentially be William Butler Yeats, as Declan Kiberd suggests, or perhaps even Joyce himself.
>
> <sub>Sam Slote (2009). ‘[Garryowen and the Bloody Mangy Mongrel of Irish Modernity](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20789628)’. *James Joyce Quarterly* 46:3/4, p. 552.</sub>

The parenthetical “wild horses shall not drag it from us” also remains a puzzle. I can only guess that this is a joke that would be clearer if we were experts on the Gaelic revival. Perhaps the joke is that Hyde’s pseudonym was not actually very pseudonymous since his published work has both names: see for example the [title page for *Love Songs of Connacht*](https://archive.org/details/LoveSongsOfConnacht).

Comment: Thanks!  I corrected the transcription error (banns for ranns) in the question.

Comment: I don’t see that the “wild horses” reference is to the same person as “Little Sweet Branch”. The former person appears to be engaged in literary criticism, and the latter person to be generating verse.

Comment: @RLH: Joyce doesn't say that "Little Sweet Branch" *wrote* the delightful lovesongs, only that he "familiarised the bookloving world" with them, i.e. collected them into book form, as Hyde did with the *Love Songs of Connacht*. I've added a couple of lines of evidence to the answer showing that Joyce meant the "phonetic expert" to be Hyde.

Comment: I started an answer along these lines but the more I read the sentence the more I became convinced he's *not* talking about Hyde here. If he was, why the "wild horses shall not drag it from us" before revealing the answer directly after? And parsing the sentence it seems to suggest that Joyce isn't referring to Hyde as the phonetics expert: i.e. "We are not speaking so much" ... "but rather".

Comment: @MattThrower I gave two lines of evidence that Joyce means the "phonetic expert" to be Hyde. Do you not find "striking" convincing? (The "We are not speaking so much ... but rather" refers to the "ranns of the Celtic bards", not to the "phenetic expert".)

Comment: @GarethRees Yes, it does seem convincing evidence. I didn't get that far in my research before giving up, but if it's correct, it still leaves me very puzzled as to why Joyce chose to structure the sentence in that manner to suggest that he did not mean to refer to Hyde.

Comment: @MattThrower I added a note on "wild horses", which remains a puzzle.